# Passing array of id's as query parameter of net/http

Tags: ruby, net-http

I want to do a GET request like that using the standard Ruby client net/http:

`stores/?ids=2,24,13`

I'm trying to do it this way, where store_ids is an array of ids, but it is not working. If I pass a single id as a param for ids, the response is correct.

```rb
def get_stores_info
  uri = URI(BASE_URL)
  params = { ids: store_ids, offset: DEFAULT_OFFSET, limit: DEFAULT_LIMIT }
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body
  result = JSON.parse response
end
```

Comment: Do you want the ids to be just like that? `ids=2,24,13`? How are you handling that on the backend? Usually, `id[]=1&id[]=24&id[]=13` should be sent in query string for Rails to get in params as... `params[:id] = [2,24,13]`.

Comment: I don't have control over the backend, so I need to build the request like that: ds=2,24,13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform `store_ids` to string:

```
store_ids = [2,24,13]
params = { ids: store_ids.join(','), offset: 0, limit: 25 }

# these are to see that it works.
encoded = URI.encode_www_form(params) # => "ids=%5B2%2C+24%2C+13%5D&offset=0&limit=25"
CGI.unescape(encoded) # => ids=2,24,13&offset=0&limit=25
```

Here's a [Replit](https://replit.com/@razvan-sv/DeadMintyCygwin).